# eBay API returns JSON when text/plain is specified in header

Tags: c++, json, rest, sdk, ebay-api

I'm looking for some perspective. I'm entirely new to API programming. I've found that calling eBay's `GeteBayTime` method is correctly returning JSON but with a header of `text/plain;charset=utf-8`, not `application/json`. Is this an eBay bug, just average API weirdness, acceptable in some way or what? Could it be an error on my part? I'm using C++ Rest SDK for client API access.

The solution, for those who face the same issue, is to change the response header using `set_content_type()`:

```
    if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        response.headers().set_content_type(L"application/json");
        return response.extract_json();
    }
```

The actual request uses:

```
http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GeteBayTime&responseencoding=JSON&appid=<my appid>&siteid=0&version=713
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a good response at https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/470633. I believe there's more room for discussion. Until then, this will be the standing answer.

Comment: How to send a GET request and receive JSON as result instead of text? I didn't see any solutions based on your link. I'm running into the same issue, I always get text/plain even though I set the Accept and Content-type headers to application/json